Thales HSM How to read response - Import Public Key (EO)
I have executed this command, but when I receive a response from HSM: HDRAEP00?5\b?0G\u0002@?!>??'&\u0016\u0005?\u0014?]n??/?n ?????? N?l???\u0004????1?x??}\u0019??\u001b??W$\0?C?:???\u0006?\0R%\u0002\u0003\u0001\ 0\u0001\
I don't know how to read ?5\b?0G\u0002@?!>??'&\u0016\u0005?\u0014?]n??/?n ?????? N?l???\u0004????1?x??}\u0019??\u001b??W$\0?C?:???\u0006?\0R%\u0002\u0003\u0001\ 0\u0001\ to get the appropriate values ​​like Hmac, public key because it bits
I tried reading it but it didn't work

please refer to EP command (response to EO) specification.


The question had examples of input and output. The answer could be improved with a worked example of interpreting that output.
